# Cannot set maintenance policy on a instance template from the command line

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have tried to set in a new instances template the maintenance policy to "MIGRATE" and the automatic restart to "On" (as the Web Console does); but it ignores the flags.

This is the command I am using:

```
gcloud compute instance-templates create \
  $TEMPLATE_NAME \
  --boot-disk-size 50GB \
  --image coreos-beta-681-0-0-v20150527 \
  --image-project coreos-cloud \
  --machine-type n1-standard-2 \
  --metadata-from-file user-data=my-cloud-config.yml \
  --scopes compute-rw,storage-full,logging-write \
  --tags web-minion \
  --maintenance-policy MIGRATE \
  --boot-disk-type pd-standard
```

But the template is created with Automatic restart to "Off" and On host maintenance to "Terminate VM instance". Instances created from this template have also the same settings.

When I log HTTP requests and responses this appears in the create request:

```
{"automaticRestart": true, "onHostMaintenance": "MIGRATE"}
```

so it does not seem a client error.

How can I create templates with the same settings the Web Console uses?

**EDIT:** Version of gcloud: 0.9.61; Version of compute: 2015.05.19.

**EDIT 2:** This also occurs now in Developers Console; it's a regression because I had a template with the correct values before.

Comment: Can you please add the output of `gcloud info` to your question? That will help in the investigation. You can mask out the personal information (email address, project name, username, etc.), the important bits are the version numbers of your installed components. Thanks!

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/google-compute-engine/issues/detail?id=199

Comment: @Kamran Thanks; didn't know GCE had an issue tracker. I've starred the bug to follow it.

Comment: @MishaBrukman Sorry; I forgot to add it; anyway it's the same that issue has.

Comment: @ernestoalejo: update on the linked bug above: _"The issue is confirmed. All new instance templates are affected. We should release a fix within a week."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-compute-engine/issues/detail?id=199) has been fixed and now I can create templates with the correct settings.